# SocketIO failing silently with flask-socketio/redis

Tags: python-3.x, flask, redis, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a flask app that runs with socketio, and has worked in production for a long time. After a MacOS 12.3 upgrade, the virtual environment stopped working so I have rebuilt it. Now the app runs locally, but SocketIO fails silently, in that it does not connect and the app cannot make any further http requests/navigate to other pages without restarting the app. There is nothing showing on the server side to indicate a problem.

Server side snippet:

```
app=Flask(__name__,static_folder="static", template_folder="templates")

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=config.SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 10 * 1024 * 1024
app.secret_key=config.APP_SECRET_KEY
api=Api(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue=config.REDIS_URL, cors_allowed_origins="*",logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
```

On the client, any page that runs this will freeze (socket will show 'connected: false'):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
```

However, if I run the app without redis running, socketio shows as connected on the client, and the app works normally (until the redis message queue is required). How should I diagnose and resolve the issue?

Note:

Is this something to do with gevent and Python compatibility? I am running:

Python 3.9.4
gevent 21.12.0
eventlet 0.33.0
greenlet 1.1.2
redis 4.1.4

Comment: Are you using gevent or eventlet? You can't be using both. Also, did you monkey patch the standard library? Redis will not work under gevent or eventlet without monkey patching.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. I am using gevent with monkey patch, eventlet does not feature in my code. If I delete eventlet from the virtual environment, this fixes the problem. I don't understand why?

Comment: That is because you did not explicitly tell Flask-SocketIO that you are using gevent. If you don't declare what you are using, Flask-SocketIO checks what's installed in the system to make a guess. Eventlet is checked before gevent. This is explained in the documentation, under the async_mode argument to the `SocketIO` class.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your help Miguel.